# Trying to call an ASP classic page from an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

That is, in the codebehind of an ASP.NET page I am trying to call an ASP classic page. I am trying this way:

```
...
Dim full As String

full = "<script type=""text/javascript"">window.open(""/FSP_LOCAL_31900_8/script/solicitudesoferta/confirmoferta2.asp"",""fraCOConfirmacion"");<" & "/script>"

Response.Write(full)
...
```

But it looks like this doesn't work.
Any idea will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors on the page? Does the resulting HTML (via View Source in the browser) contain the expected JavaScript?

Comment: Is this in a handler? Can you use Page.RegisterClientScript instead maybe?

Comment: I am not getting any JavaScript error, and in the resulting HTML I can see the JavaScript:

</script><script type="text/javascript">window.open("/FSP_LOCAL_31900_8/script/solicitudesoferta/confirmoferta2.asp","fraCOConfirmacion");</script>

It is just like if it isn't there in the HTML, but I can see it.

Comment: The code is inside the handler for page load. I am going to try the way you say, Andrew, thanks for the idea.

Comment: What I want to accomplish is to launch the ASP classic page just after the load method of the ASP.NET page has ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Response.Write(full)`, you are sending the string right above any HTML content that already exist, hence it'll not work.

Instead, use:

```
Dim full As String
full = "window.open('/FSP_LOCAL_31900_8/script/solicitudesoferta/confirmoferta2.asp','fraCOConfirmacion');"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myscript", full, true);
```

Note that I've removed the `<script>` tags from your string, since the last parameter of `RegisterStartupScript` indicates if you want or not to add the tag.

Comment: Your first sentence is not correct. Response.Write will put the given string above the `<html>` and the `<doctype>` so modern browsers will just ignore it, being invalid noise.

Comment: It works, the browser opens a new window. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've improved my answer.